# Which is the best way to represent power of negative values

Tags: c

I want to use C program to calculate permitivity of some materiel. The formula to calculate permitivity is

```
E= Cx/Co;
Co= 15.88pF = 15.88*10^-12;
Cx=1/W.C;
W= 2*pi*f=2*pi*250000;
C= Cs/(1+tan^2(theta));
Cs=1;
theta=0 degree;
```

I have tried to implement the above formula in C with the fallowing code.

```
float E, Cx, Co= 15.88*10^-12;, Cs=1.0; f=250*10^3,Pi=3.14,theta=0.0;

angle= theta/180*pi;  // to convert degree to radians
W= 2*pi*f;
C= Cs/(1+tan^2(angle));
Cx=1/W.C;
E= Cx/Co;

printf("permitivity value: %.10f",E);
```

I am confusing in the representation of power values like

> 10^-12, tan^2(angle).

Is it correct the way I represent? I am not getting exact value what I have calculated with manually. Is there any better way to represent power values? I want to display float value 10 digits after point, like 0.0000000000. But i am able to display only six digits after point.

Any one help me with the correct way to calculate permitivity.

Comment: Try using "%g" for formatting.

Comment: You could try with `double` or `long double` to get better precision.

Comment: That's not the point... OP fails to use the `^` operator, see my answer.

Comment: @user1759248 Why don't you read a C reference, btw?

Comment: I think you should try OCTAVE instead of C. OCTAVE is kinda language for mathematical stuff. Its easy to learn, and lots of maths is already implemented in it. Its also free. Here is the link : http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you had read up on C operators...

The `^` operator performs a bitwise XOR which is not what you want. You need to either use the standard library function `pow()` from `<math.h>` to calculate powers, or use the scientific notation:

```
Co = 15.88E-12;

C = Cs / (1 + pow(tan(angle), 2));
```

Also note that this is not math, this is C, and you **cannot** write `tan ^ 2(argument)`, you can only call a function and not a "function squared" as in math notation...

Comment: was about to say that. Same thing about `tan^2(theta)`...

Comment: @H2CO3 I have small doubt Can i use tan^2(theta) as tan(theta)*tan(theta).

Comment: @user1759248 yes, that's possible.

Comment: @H2CO3 Can you help me how to print 10 digits after decimal point. like 1.987965432 in float. I have tried like "%2.10f" but its not working, it is printing only 6(six) digits after decimal point.My complier is not supporting Double.

Comment: `pow` is a **really bad** (in terms of performance and accuracy requirement) way to write "squared". To square a quantity, just multiply it by itself.

Comment: @R.. well, yes. I didn't say it was good.

Comment: Well I don't think it's a good idea to include bad patterns in answers when the OP didn't already use the bad pattern. Obviously OP here does not know how to do math in C, and introducing `pow` as the way to square numbers is just teaching bad habits.

Comment: @R.. see the first comment of the OP to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are thinking mathematical expressions can be written the same way in C, which is not correct. Even the same symbols have totally different meaning. Learn a bit of C syntax first.